# Extrair par chave/valor de uma querystring

Tags: php, array

Tenho este código onde recebo o valor de um post e ajax.

```
 $string = 'nome=Alexandre+Sousa&cpf=0000000000000&email=sousa.akira%40gmail.com&site=www.uniaomaker.com.br';

$dados = explode('&',$string);
$total = count($dados);
$array = '';
foreach ($dados as $list) {
    $vals = explode('=',$list);
    $array .= '"'.$vals[0].'"'. '=>'.'"'.$vals[1].'"'.',';
}

$keys = array($array);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($keys);
```

O resultado que eu recebo e o seguinte

> Array (
>       [0] => "nome"=>"Alexandre+Sousa","cpf"=>"0000000000000","email"=>"sousa.akira%40gmail.com","site"=>"www.uniaomaker.com.br",
>   )

Porém eu preciso que o array retorne desta forma

> Array (
>       [nome] => Alexandre+Sousa
>       [cpf] => 0000000000000
>       [email] => sousa.akira%40gmail.com
>       [site] => www.uniaomaker.com.br )

Já tentei muitas dicas mais não encontrei solução,

Comment: Você esta retornando um array dentro de outro array, para que retorne o que você necessita, deveria retornar cada elemento como uma posição do array

Comment: poderia me da uma ajuda com o código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você precisa transformar essa querystring em um array use a função [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) para isso:

```
<?php

$str = "nome=Alexandre+Sousa&cpf=0000000000000&email=sousa.akira%40gmail.com&site=www.uniaomaker.com.br";
parse_str($str, $valores);

print_r($valores);
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [nome] => Alexandre Sousa
    [cpf] => 0000000000000
    [email] => sousa.akira@gmail.com
    [site] => www.uniaomaker.com.br
)
```

[Exemplo - ideone](https://ideone.com/fcsHWx)

Comment: Obrigado amigo salvo minha pele

Answer (score 2):

É mais prático usando a função `parse_str()` devido ao formato da string.

Todavia, o script original já estava quase lá..
Bastava preencher um array associativo ao invés de concatenar os dados como uma variável comum.

```
 $string = 'nome=Alexandre+Sousa&cpf=0000000000000&email=sousa.akira%40gmail.com&site=www.uniaomaker.com.br';

$dados = explode('&',$string);
$total = count($dados);
$array = '';
foreach ($dados as $list) {
    $vals = explode('=',$list);
    $array[$vals[0]] = $vals[1];
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
```